# Double Numerical Integration in C++

Tags: c++, boost, integration, numerical

I am looking for a good way to compute a double integral numerically using pre-written C++ libraries. The basic integral I'm dealing with is this:

> [image: <code>\int_{b}^{c}\int_{a}^{f(y)} f(x,y) dx dy</code>]

I've done some research and discovered a few libraries that might be useful, however I'm not sure which one to choose based on the problem I'm dealing with. The libraries I have looked at are

1. GSL - The problem here is it's written in C and so I would have to
   find some kind of wrapper to make it compatible with my research
   codes.
2. Cuba - This library seems very appropriate and well documented.
   However I would like to avoid importing an entirely new library if I
   can because I'm already importing Boost and Blitz and would like to
   keep the hassle of compiling everything to a minimum.
3. Boost - From what I have read in their documentation Boost has
   methods for integrating ODE's, but I could not find any libraries
   for numerically integrating double integrals of functions. Am I
   missing something? This would be the most convenient option as I
   already use Boost in my codes and its already in C++.

So my question essentially boils down to this:

Which of these three libraries would be most useful for my purposes? Is it possible to conduct the integral I have specified using Boost? Additionally any tips on how to implement this integral using any of the above libraries would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these sources, calling c code from c++ is generally not problematic.  It's going the other direction that can be.

[How to mix C and C++](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp)

[How to Call C Function in C++, C++ Function in C (Mix C and C++)](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/01/mix-c-and-cpp/)